# Datatable - Server side data is not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-5

I am playing with `datatable` with `Laravel 5` with first time so I tried with this code and I am getting data on ajax but not able to display data on my `datatable`.

Any Idea how to load response data to datatable.

### Here is my structure:

### Result:

[image]

### Route:

```
Route::get('admin/pages/datatable', 'admin\PagesController@getDataTable'); // Pages (Static Pages)
```

### pages.blade.php:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Pages Table</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="example32" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>PageId</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Text</th>
                                <th>MetaKeywords</th>
                                <th>MetaDescription</th>
                                <th>PostedBy</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>PageId</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Text</th>
                                <th>MetaKeywords</th>
                                <th>MetaDescription</th>
                                <th>PostedBy</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

### PagesController.php:

```
public function getDataTable()
{
    $Pages = new Pages();
    return $GetAllPages = $Pages->GetPages();
}
```

### Pages.php:

```
public function GetPages()
{
    return DB::table('pages')->select('PageId', 'Title', 'Text', 'MetaKeywords', 'MetaDescription', 'PostedBy')
            ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an indexed array instead of associative. Your response should be like

```
{['pageid', 'Title', 'Text', ... ]}
```

Just need to follow the correct column order.

May be you can use,

```
public function GetPages()
{
     $pages = DB::table('pages')->select('PageId', 'Title', 'Text', 'MetaKeywords', 'MetaDescription', 'PostedBy')->get();
     $pages = $pages->map(function($item){
         return [$item->PageId, $item->Title,$item->Text,$item->MetaKeywords,$item->MetaDescription, $item->PostedBy ];
     });
     return $pages;
}
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::map()`

Comment: Sorry! try adding `->get()` after `$pages = DB::table('pages')->select('PageId', 'Title', 'Text', 'MetaKeywords', 'MetaDescription', 'PostedBy')`. I Updated the answer.